# Using subplot2grid with 'AxesSubplot' object

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I'm using subplot2grid to define a grid of plots as shown below.
Works great, it's a good functionality.

```
    plot_axes_1 = plt.subplot2grid((6, 4), (0, 0), rowspan=2, colspan=3)  ##1
    plot_axes_2 = plt.subplot2grid((6, 4), (2, 0), rowspan=2, colspan=3, sharex=scatter_axes_1)  ##2
    
    x_hist_axes_2 = plt.subplot2grid((6, 4), (4, 0), colspan=3, sharex=scatter_axes_2) ##3
    
    y_hist_axes_1 = plt.subplot2grid((6, 4), (0, 3), rowspan=2, sharey=scatter_axes_1)  ##4
    y_hist_axes_2 = plt.subplot2grid((6, 4), (2, 3), rowspan=2, sharey=scatter_axes_2, sharex= y_hist_axes_1)  ##5
```

[image: grid]

Now I want to consider the 5 plots from the image as a unit, and plot 6 copies of it, arranged on 3 rows and 2 columns.

```
    fig, ax= plt.subplots(3,2)

    for l in range(3):
        for m in range(2):

            ax[l,m].subplot2grid((6, 4), (0, 0), rowspan=2, colspan=3)  ##1
            ax[l,m].subplot2grid((6, 4), (2, 0), rowspan=2, colspan=3, sharex=scatter_axes_1)  ##2

            ax[l,m].subplot2grid((6, 4), (4, 0), colspan=3, sharex=scatter_axes_2) ##3

            ax[l,m].subplot2grid((6, 4), (0, 3), rowspan=2, sharey=scatter_axes_1)  ##4
            ax[l,m].subplot2grid((6, 4), (2, 3), rowspan=2, sharey=scatter_axes_2, sharex= y_hist_axes_1)  ##5
```

But I can't use subplot2grid like this, I get the error
`'AxesSubplot' object has no attribute 'subplot2grid'`

Is there another function I can use with AxesSubplot to do that?

Comment: Just to clarify, by plotting six copies of the above figure, you mean that you need a total of 30 subplots (effectively 4 columns and 9 rows)?

Comment: Right, in total 30 subplots,  9 rows 4 columns

Comment: Great. I added an answer assuming that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm a little confused by what you are trying to do.  However, a perhaps an alternate way to deal with different widths and heights is to use width ratios?

EDIT:  use subfigure to keep logical groups of axes.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure(constrained_layout=True, figsize=(8, 12))
sfigs = fig.subfigures(3, 2)
for nn, sf in enumerate(sfigs.flat):
    sf.suptitle(nn)
    axs = sf.subplots(3, 2, gridspec_kw={'width_ratios': [2, 1],
                                         'height_ratios': [2, 2, 1]})
    sf.delaxes(axs[2, 1])
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I clarified better what I needed, which was 6 times this. But thank you for this approach. It is simpler than my way for plotting the main 5 axes at least.

Comment: I would use subfigure(3,2) and then populate as above.

Comment: Wow, didn't know about `subfigures`. Seems amazing! This is matplotlib >= 3.4, right?

Comment: yes subfigures is brand new, as is subplot_mosaic.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a job for matplotlib's [sematic figure composition function](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/provisional/mosaic.html), i.e., the `subplot_mosaic` function. This is available in matplotlib > 3.3. You will need to define a basic layout for your 5 panels, and then generate a full layout depending on how many rows/columns you want. As far as I can see, this will be quite convoluted and hard (although not impossible!) to create by `subplot2grid` or `Gridspec` or any of the other approaches.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def layout(panel, rows=3, cols=2, empty_sentinal=999):
    """Takes in a single layout and arranges it in multiple
       rows and columns"""
    
    npanels = rows * cols
    panel[panel >= empty_sentinal] = empty_sentinal
    minipanels = len(np.unique(panel))

    panels = np.array([i * (minipanels) + panel for i in range(npanels)])
        
    panel_rows = [np.hstack(panels[i : i + cols]) for i in range(0, npanels, cols)]
    panel_cols = np.vstack(panel_rows)
    
    panel_cols[panel_cols > empty_sentinal] = empty_sentinal
    
    return panel_cols
```

A) Generating a single panel:

```py
single_panel = np.array([
    [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 999], 
    [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 999], 
    [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 999], 
    [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 999], 
    [3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 999], 
    [3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 999], 
    [3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 999], 
    [3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 999], 
    [5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 999, 999, 999],
    [5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 999, 999, 999],
    [5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 999, 999, 999],
    [999] * 9,
    [999] * 9,
])

fig, ax = plt.subplot_mosaic(single_panel, figsize=(10, 10), empty_sentinel=999)
for k, v in ax.items():
    v.set_xticklabels([])
    v.set_yticklabels([])
    v.text(0.5, 0.5, k, ha="center", va="center", fontsize=25)

plt.show()
```

[image: Single Layout]

(B) "Tiling" the above single panel

```py
my_layout = layout(panel=single_panel, rows=3, cols=2)
    
fig, ax = plt.subplot_mosaic(my_layout, figsize=(10, 10), empty_sentinel=999)
for k, v in ax.items():
    v.set_xticklabels([])
    v.set_yticklabels([])
    v.text(0.5, 0.5, k, ha="center", va="center", fontsize=25)

plt.show()
```

[image: Tiled Single Panel]

Some Notes:

1. The `empty_sentinal` is set to 999. If you have more than 999 subplots, increase that to a higher number.
2. Each "mini-panel" can be individually acessed. You might need to write other functions to access "panel-group"